# Why dagger errors are not showing up in the editor?

Tags: android-studio, dagger, dagger-2

I'm using dagger 2.0 in a project with android studio and I was expecting the compilation errors from the annotation processor to show up in the editor as actual compilation errors (red underline).

I've tried enabling "make project automatically" but still doesn't work. Off course the errors show up in the compiler log when I manually make the project with ctrl+f9.

So, not a big deal, dagger is working perfectly, but the thing is that in the presentation I saw this:

[image: slide]

But to be fair it only says javac or eclipse :P

Answer (score 1):

That functionality doesn't exist in Android Studio.

You can find plugins to do something similar.

For example: https://github.com/square/dagger-intellij-plugin

Comment: I used that plugin with the old version and it only links injection points with providers, and looks that it doesn't have support for dagger 2.0 https://github.com/square/dagger-intellij-plugin/issues/16